# CSS div height 100% not working

Tags: html, css

div2 is 1000px height because of div4, div5 and div6. I'm not understanding why div3 isn't getting the 100% height, it is 0px height.

```
<div id="div1" class="center" style="width:1024px; height:auto;">
    <div id="div2" style="float:left; width:100%; height:auto;">
        <div id="div3" style="float:left; width:460px; height:100%; background-image:url(img/bgVictorMonteiro.jpg); background-size:100% auto; background-position:bottom; background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
        <div id="div4" style="float:left; width:270px; height:1000px;"></div>
        <div id="div5" style="float:left; width:25px; height:1000px;"></div>
        <div id="div6" style="float:left; width:269px; height:1000px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because parent has height auto: percentages only work if a fixed parent height is setted.

Comment: and don´t forget to set on `body,html{height:100%;}`

Comment: If you are setting the height to 1000px on all divs except for one which is 100% why don't you just set div2's height to 1000px and do away with all the height's set on the child divs all together?

Comment: @Onheiron, are you sure? there's no way to do this? I really need that div to have auto height

Comment: @LuisP.A., that doesn't apply here!

Comment: @ZacBraddy, 1000px values are just for testing purposes

Comment: you can do it with a little jquery if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the height of parent `div1` to `1000px` and set the children's height to `:inherit`.
Here's an example:

```css
#div1
{
    width:1024px;
    height:1000px;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#div2
{    
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:inherit;
    background:yellow;
}
#div3
{    
    float:left;
    width:460px;
    height:inherit;
    background-image:url('http://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/r_dc/caplio/r7/img/sample_04.jpg');
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#div4
{
    float:left; 
    width:270px;
    height:inherit;
    background:violet;
}

#div5
{
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:inherit;
    background:black;
}

#div6
{
    float:left;
    width:269px;
    height:inherit;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="center">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3"></div>
        <div id="div4"></div>
        <div id="div5" ></div>
        <div id="div6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It could be a workaround. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

Using a percentage based `height` relies on an explicit `height` value being set on the parent element:

> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the root element is relative to the initial containing block.

*Content height: the 'height' property (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property)*

In this case the parent element is `#div2` which has `height: auto;`. This means that its `height` depends on the `height` of its content and is not explicitly declared.

If you were to apply the `height` explicitly to `#div2` (e.g. `height: 1000px;`) then using `height: 100%;` on `#div3` would work.

```css
#div1 {
    width:1024px;
    height:auto;
}
#div2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
}
#div3 {
    float:left;
    width:460px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
}
#div4 {
    float:left;
    width:270px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color: green;
}
#div5 {
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div6 {
    float:left;
    width:269px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3"></div>
        <div id="div4"></div>
        <div id="div5"></div>
        <div id="div6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One possible way of ensuring that `#div3` uses the full `height` without setting it explicitly on `#div2` is to use `flexbox`.

```css
#div1 {
    width:1024px;
    height:auto;
}
#div2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display: flex;
}
#div3 {
    width:460px;
    background-color: red;
}
#div4 {
    width:270px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color: green;
}
#div5 {
    width:25px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div6 {
    width:269px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3"></div>
        <div id="div4"></div>
        <div id="div5"></div>
        <div id="div6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The root of your problem, because it's a div within a div 100% takes value from its container, as in, if the parent div had a height of 50px, 100% on the child div would mean it would have the height of 50px but your parent div has the height of auto so it's taken whatever height that is :) hope this helps :p

Comment: The inline style is just for testing eheh.

Wrong, that's the problem. The parent div is 1000px height, because of the other divs inside that have 1000px height (for testing purposes).

Comment: ahh ok no worries then haha :) 2nd part confused me a little??