# Why image doesnt fit parent div height?

Tags: html, css

I have situation like this

[image]

Both divs have the same height, image width scales fine but height doesn't. In productLogo class I set width and height to 100% - no results, I also tried with min and max height. Can you tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Setting the height to 100% has no effect unless the parent container actually has a specified height. (100% of nothing is nothing.) Does your parent container have a height?

Comment: Yeah- that was the problem. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS div height 100% not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298338/css-div-height-100-not-working)